# Is ISNUMBER(MATCH) limited to a range>

Tags: excel, match

I am trying to check if a value in 1 cell is the same as in specific other cells. I thought that I needed to use something like =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,A2:A10,0)),1,0) to produce a result, but I don't want it to check a list of values, just certain cells. I have tried =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,(A2,A4,A7,A8,A10),0)),1,0) for example, but that doesn't seem to work. I need to cross reference that cell with about 30 other cells, so want to avoid nested "IF"s unless absolutely necessary. Several of the intervening cells will have the value that I am checking for, which is why I can't use a range.
Thanks!

Comment: Let's call the two cells you want to check for equality `A1` and `B1`. Then you can simply write `=(A1=B1)`.

Comment: Thanks Xavier - but I am trying to compare 1 cell with about 30 other cells in the same formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following array formula:

```
=AND(C1=INDEX(C1:C10,N(IF(1,{2,4,7,8,10}))))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

or without array:

```
=VAR(--(C1=INDEX(C1:C10,N(IF(1,{2,4,7,8,10})))))=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since `=(A1 = A2) will` return `True` *(or 1)* if **A1** equals **A2**; how about:

```
=OR(A1=A2,A1=A4,A1=A7,A1=A8,A1=A10)
```

[image]

We get true because **A1** matches **A7**.

**NOTE:**

If you prefer *1/0* rather than *True/False*, use:

```
=OR(A1=A2,A1=A4,A1=A7,A1=A8,A1=A10)*1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the cells do not line up in a single column, one can use OR and CHOOSE:

```
=OR(A1=CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6},A2,A4,A7,A8,A9,C4))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]